# Why is this subspectrum closed

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $u: X \to X $ be a compact operator on a Banach space $X$ and let $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ be non zero. We know that $u-\lambda$ is Fredholm and that $X=\mathrm{ker}(u-\lambda)^n \oplus \mathrm{im}(u-\lambda)^n$ for some $n$. Consider the map $u\mid_{\mathrm{im}}=u\mid_{\mathrm{im}(u-\lambda)^n}$.

Why is the spectrum $\sigma(u\mid_{\mathrm{im}})$ closed in $\sigma (u)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $u|_{im}$ is compact because $u$ is compact.

If $u|_{im}x=\mu x$ for some $x\ne 0$, then $ux=\mu x$. Therefore, $\sigma(u|_{im})\subseteq \sigma(u)$.

If $ux=\mu x$ for some $\mu\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\lambda\}$ and some $x \ne 0$, then $x \in \mbox{im}$ because
$$
                          x = \frac{1}{(\mu-\lambda)^{n}}(u-\lambda I)^{n}x.
$$
Therefore, $\sigma(u)\setminus\{\lambda\} \subseteq \sigma(u|_{min})$.

Finally, notice that $u|_{im}$ does not have eigenvalue $\lambda$ because $u|_{im}-\lambda I$ is invertible on 'im'. So $\sigma(u|_{im})=\sigma(u)\setminus\{\lambda\}$, which is closed in $\sigma(u)$ because the non-zero eigenvalues of $u$ are isolated.

Comment: Thank you. Meanwhile I think I found a (different) proof. Can you tell me if one could also argue like this? I have a theorem stating that in a Banach algebra $A$ for all $a$, $\sigma(a)$ is closed in $\mathbb C$. From this it follows immediately. Right?

Comment: You have to first argue that $\sigma(u|_{im})\subseteq\sigma(u)$. Then you can use the fact that $\sigma(u|_{im})$ is closed.

Comment: Ok, great, so if I first prove that $\sigma(u|_{im})\subseteq\sigma(u)$ then I can apply the theorem that says $\sigma (a)$ is closed etc.?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is a correct approach.